# Upgrading Next.js Project to v13: ISR Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm in the middle of upgrading my Next.js project from version 12 to version 13, and I've run into an issue with handling errors.

Specifically, I've discovered that getStaticProps is no longer available in version 13, and I can't seem to set the revalidation timer to properly handle errors.

I'm curious if anyone else has encountered this issue and has found a way to work around it. I've tried a few different approaches, but so far nothing has worked. If anyone has any suggestions or insights, I'd be grateful to hear them.

firebase fetch:

```
async function fetchCategoryData(
  category: string
): Promise<SimplifiedArticle[]> {
  const newsDocRef = collection(firestore, "news");
  const q = query(
    newsDocRef,
    where("category", "==", category),
    orderBy("publishedAt", "desc"),
    limit(5)
  );
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
  const product: SimplifiedArticle[] = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
    const docData = doc.data();
    return {
      title: docData.title || "",
      url: docData.url || "",
      imageUrl: docData.imageUrl || "",
      description: docData.description || "",
      publishedAt: docData.publishedAt || "",
      content: docData.content || "",
      source: docData.source || "",
    };
  });
  return product;
}
```

version 12 code:

```
export async function getStaticProps(context: GetStaticPropsContext) {
  try {
    const news: FetchNews = await Promise.all(
      categories.map(async (category) => ({
        [category]: await fetchCategoryData(category),
      }))
    ).then(Object.assign.bind(null, {}));

    return {
      props: { news },
      revalidate: 3600,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("News getStaticProps error: ", error);
    return { notFound: true, revalidate: 60 }; //re-fetch after 1 min if error
  }
}
```

Next js source:
https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/fetching

Data Fetching without fetch()

```
import prisma from './lib/prisma';

export const revalidate = 3600; // revalidate every hour

async function getPosts() {
  const posts = await prisma.post.findMany();
  return posts;
}

export default async function Page() {
  const posts = await getPosts();
  // ...
}
```

export const revalidate = 3600; // revalidate every hour

## I've tried to set the revalidation timer for 3600 seconds, but I'm still unable to handle errors.

## How can I properly set the revalidation timer for error handling? (60s timer)